# weak IBOutlet UIView property would become nil

Tags: ios, properties, weak-references, iboutlet

I have two UIViews in the nib file and I set them to be properties of my view controller, using the `IBOutlet` and `weak` keyword.

However, when I use `self.view1` which I want to use to point to the view in the nib, for the first time, it works. But when I use it later, these two properties turn to be `nil`.

Using the `strong` property would fix the issue. But I always use `weak` for the `IBOutlet` property. Why it becomes nil in this situation?

Comment: Your weak outlet will become `nil` if there is no reference to it. This can happen with a view that doesn't have a `superview`.

Comment: **But when I use it later, these two properties turn to be nil** -  mean, how you are deal with it ..?

Comment: @rmaddy you really remind me.

Comment: @KumarKl I did `removeFromSuperview`, and when I wanted to add them back, they were found to be nil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have a `strong` reference to top level items in a nib file. If you have two views at the top level of your nib, then you should have `strong` references to them, not `weak` ones.

Any subviews of these top level views can be made `IBOutlets` with `weak` references, because the top level view keeps a strong reference to these subviews, so you don't have to.

Most times, `weak` is good enough, because there is an implicit `strong` reference to the top level object. For Example, if you have a nib for a view controller, then the view controller object maintains a strong reference to the top level view because of it's `view` property, which means that you can have a `weak` hold on any other objects.

Comment: As you said. I do did some operations like `removeFromSuperview`, after that the weak properties became nil. Thanks to @rmaddy, when I saw his comment I realized where my mistake was.